# AngularJS - Request timeout although resource exists

Tags: angularjs

I've created a web application on a Raspberry Pi, this one simply have to do some HTTP requests to a gateway (the gateway and the Raspberry Pi are on the same network). HTTP requests are made in Angular, like that:

```
$http.get("http://192.168.3.9:8081/command=get?token").success(function(data){
    console.log("token is: "+data);
}).error(function(data, status, headers, config){
    console.log("unable to find token");
    console.log(data);
    console.log(status);
    console.log(headers);
    console.log(config);
});
```

Now here there's a problem, I expected either to have a response or to have an error from CORS instead I receive an error that says me the requests is ended due to timeout.
This is not possible because the request URL is absolutely correct. How to solve this problem?
P.S.: An information that could be useful: the gateway and the Raspberry Pi are in my home network, but I connect with my PC to the Raspberry from my office network.

Comment: Paste that URL in your browser, just to see if you can a response. This is almost certainly a firewall issue.

Comment: From which network? my home network or my office network?

Comment: Mostly from office, but both would make sure.

Comment: I've already tried and I haven't any response, even if try with gateway's public address. May I allow a global access to router's 8081 port?

Comment: As a temporary check, some routers will allow you to move your RPi into a DMZ and receive all requests. If this works then you're missing router configuraiton: Have you added a route to your router's NAT table to route 8081 to your RPi?

Comment: To be honest no, I thought it wasn't necessary because the RPi and the gateway are on the same network

Comment: I was assuming that the code sample is from angular though, which is running in the client's browser. Is that right it is it in nodejs?

Comment: Correct, server side is build with node.js

Comment: But is the code shown in angular or in node?

Comment: Actually, its using `$http.get`, so its Angular.

Comment: That code is from the client side (Angular)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here is that you have your `$http.get` running in the client's browser.

Therefore you have two separate problems - you need to be able to resolve your IP address/URL, and you need the Port number to reach the host.

The 192.168... address is a LAN ip, so only makes sense within your home network. The port 8081 we need to be able to reach your RPi through your gateway once you fix your IP/URL issue.

You've not really made your full infrastructure clear - if your RPi is your whole server side infrastructure (ie there isn't a separate webserver), then you need to either have a static WAN ip for your home network, or configure a host name that gets updated with your dynamic IP (see ddclient or similar).

If you do have a separate webserver which you're able to reach ok, then consider having a controller in your main website that bounces these requests on to the RPi. It will add a little overhead, but has various configuration advantages - eliminates CORS, you don't need your RPi exposes to the web etc etc.

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs because your AngularJS code is executed on the browser (on the client-side). So the requested server (192.168.3.9) is resolved according to the place your browser is.

If you're at home, it will probably work fine because the address is resolved locally (and so it will reach your gateway), but if you are at office, 192.168.3.9 will not resolve to your gateway but on a device on your local office network.